# Disable the html page resizing

Tags: html

Hi I want to disable the resizing the html web page by the user. How to do that
I want to disable the resize button and manual resizing by dragging. pls help

Comment: i think this is not possible. Maybe there is a solution for some specific browsers.

Comment: hey i also need to do what you want. Did you managed to find a solution @ganuke ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, thank God.

When you open a new popup you can request it be unresizable using the feature `resizable`:

```
window.open('something.html', '_blank', 'resizable=no');
```

however modern browsers may ignore your request as it is considered egregiously user-hostile.

Use liquid layout to make your page respond flexibly to changes in window size, rather than attempting to set it in concrete. The web is inherently a variable-size medium, and mobile browser users get no input in how large their screen is anyway.

Comment: Hmm. This works for IE but not for firefox. I wnated to do it only for ie and firefox. So can you pls tell me how to do it with forefox

Comment: Firefox disables it by default. You can go to `about:config` and alter the value `dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable` to re-enable the feature on your copy of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Pardon? Are you talking about resizing the browser window? If that's the case then you can't do this in HTML, or JavaScript as it would be a security risk allow web pages to control browsers behaviour.

If you want to get rid of scroll bars you can set the body tag to 'overflow: hidden' in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to stop the page shrinking and expanding in sympathy with browser window size, then use fixed width elements as supposed to relative (%)