# Window resize disable in html

Tags: html

I created an html page within that for few links i done an pop window with width-400 and height-200.
But the clients requirements is when window got popup the user should not resize it.
I tried with resizable=no,resizable=0 but nothing is working out, all makes window resize. 
Please help me if there is any alternate method.

Here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/uj07cf7o/7/

```
 window.open("disclaimer.jsp", "popup", "width=400,height=200",'resizable=no');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable the html page resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734400/disable-the-html-page-resizing)

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my question that resizable=no is not working

Comment: Provide a JSfiddle please

Comment: what browser are you using? Also, as stated in the answer to that question *however modern browsers may ignore your request as it is considered egregiously user-hostile.*

Comment: If you read the link @jbutler483 added, it states some browsers do not support this... but either way try a (test.html) file and instead of (popup), try (_blank) and see if there is any difference

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle, a comment below the chosen answer ALSO states *Firefox disables it by default. You can go to about:config and alter the value dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable to re-enable the feature on your copy of Firefox.*

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle Thanks for the answer. May i know from where do i get test.html file. I tried with _blank still its not working. I am using Google chrome

Comment: will the client only be using chrome, or will this 'solution' have to be cross browser? Also, https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window might hold the solution. It has a listener to see when the window is resized. How about using that and 'resetting' the size from there?

Comment: What I mean is to create a html page... But regardless I went to W3 and even their example isn't working on Chrome. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open5 you can look at it there (Just change resizable=no)

Comment: Just tested and works in IE10

Comment: Above code must work in chrome, firefox and IE. In none of the browsers its working.

Comment: then use jquery: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/ But again, unless this is *totally necessary,* and even then, **many** people agree with this being bad practise

Answer (score 1):

update like this..

```
window.open('YOURPAGE.htm', 'popper', 'directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=yes,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,height=500,width=565')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Above mentioned code is not working to me.